# How to create a component which add nothing the html

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How to create a component in Vue which just adds, say, `onmousedown` listener to its child?

Having that:

```
<div id="app" class="container">
    <foo>
        <p>hello</p>
    </foo>
</div>
```

I want the output will look like that:

```
<div id="app" class="container">
     <p>hello</p>
</div>
```

Here is my code:

```
<script id="templ-foo" type="text/templ">
    <slot></slot>            -- this doesn't work
    <div><slot></slot></div> -- this adds outer DIV element
</script>

<script>
(function () {

    var Foo = Vue.extend({
        template: '#templ-foo'
    });

    Vue.component('foo', Foo);

    new Vue({
        el: '#app'
    });

})();
</script>
```

Comment: I think you are looking for an **abstract component** like `<keep-alive>` or `<transition>`. For now the feature is meant to be internal only so there're no official docs, even though you could use it. I addressed [an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/vuejs/vuejs.org/issues/720), you could take a look. Maybe that could solve your problem. Don't forget to read source code of built-in abstract components, since... no docs. Also you could post your comment under that issue. If there are enough valid use cases I think they will consider offering the feature to app developers.

Comment: However, your case would be easier implemented with a custom directive, in my opinion. Or simply bind `v-on:mousedown` to the element you want.

Comment: And one more thing about `slot`. A default slot could be replaced by multiple elements! I'm thinking of whether this is the reason your first approach fails, since vue template must have only one root element. On the other hand, a **named slot** can only be replaced by one element with the same identity. So maybe you could try a named slot in your template. I'm not sure about it though, didn't try.

Comment: @Leo **named slot** (`<slot name="foo"></slot>` and `<foo><p slot="foo">hello</p></foo>`) doesn't work.

Comment: I would go with a mixin [vuejs docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html), You can add a listener on any lifecycle hook and than attach this mixin to all the components you wish had this functionality.